# Substitute just once, concatenate, and substitute again

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Given macro definitions like this:

```c
#define GPIOA ((1234)+42)
#define GPIOB ((1234)+84)

#define LEDA_GPIO_Port GPIOA
#define LEDB_GPIO_Port GPIOB

#define MY_PORT_GPIOA 0
#define MY_PORT_GPIOB 1
```

I would like to define a macro `MY_PORT` which, given `LEDA` as argument somehow substitutes this to `LEDA_GPIO_Port`, then to `GPIOA`, turns that into `MY_PORT_GPIOA` and this into `0`. So `MY_PORT(LEDA)` should evaluate to `0` and `MY_PORT(LEDB)` to `1`. If the macros `GPIOA`/`GPIOB` wouldn't exist, this would be easy, but since they are defined as complex expressions (starting with parentheses) only *one* substitution must be performed, and the occurence of `GPIOA` must not be substituted by that expression.

I tried

```c
#define MY_PORT2(port) MY_PORT_##port
#define MY_PORT(name) MY_PORT2(name##_GPIO_Port)
```

but here `MY_PORT(LEDA)` returns `MY_PORT_LEDA_GPIO_Port`, i.e. it lacks one substituion.

```c
#define CONCAT(a,b) a##b
#define MY_PORT2(port) CONCAT(MY_PORT,port)
#define MY_PORT(name) MY_PORT2(name##_GPIO_Port)
```

does not compile, as it tries to concatenate the definition for `GPIOA`, i.e. one subtitution too many.

Is it even possible to do exactly one subtitution?

Comment: "Is it even possible to do exactly one" Nope.